How do I read a barcode in a .Net MAUI App using a barcode scanner in an android device (not the camera)?
I have been asked to look into replacing a customer's current handheld software and devices (Windows CE 7) with android (like Tera P172 + also use on company mobiles). I want to be able to use the barcode scanner and not the camera currently, but may look at using either with a setting to determine which one to use.
I want to use .Net MAUI but am not completely sure of the best way to read the barcode.
It will only be for certain pages where it will prompt for a barcode, wait for the barcode before moving on from there.
I have seen articles on using a BroadcastReceiver, but am not completely sure of how to use it and wire it into the required views/popups?
Any help would be much appreciated...
Ade
I have tried using a BroadcastReceiver, but I am struggling to find the correct IntentFilter and KeyValueName?

You want a barcode scanner connected to your desktop app to scan barcodes?

Most hardware scanners act as keyboards, meaning when you scan they will just send their input to whatever app has focus. I’d you have an Entry field in your page that has focus, then the scanner will direct its input there.

What is the barcode scanner you are trying to use? The scanner should have some documentation on how to get the barcode. Seeing that you mentioned a BroadcastReceiver, how did you come to the decision to try using that (There are indeed integrated scanners that use a braodcast to get the barcode but there is also documentation that goes alone with it on how to listen for it)

Thanks. I had the wrong IntentFilter name and KeyValue to get the barcode out of the Intent.
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    private readonly BroadcastReceiver _barcodeReceiver = new BarcodeBroadcastReceiver();

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        RegisterReceiver(_barcodeReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.scanner.broadcast"));
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        UnregisterReceiver(_barcodeReceiver);
        base.OnPause();
    }
}
public class BarcodeBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override async void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        var barcode = intent.GetStringExtra("data");

    }
}


Take a look at this package here.
Zxing offers embedded barcode scanner with a live Camera Stream or opening up a separate activity altogether.
Documentation is available here.
https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Maui
UPDATE
This is probably what you're looking for then.
https://github.com/zebra-technologies/Scanner-SDK-for-Android

Does this support an actual barcode scanner and not just the camera?

it is a literal barcode scanner.
Take a look at the supported barcode formats here:
https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Maui/blob/main/ZXing.Net.MAUI/BarcodeFormat.cs

Cheers for the help Dan. What I mean is that the device has a Zebra SE4710 scanning module. Thanks

Ah ok, I understand what you mean by "Not the camera". So the scanner looks like this?
https://tera-digital.com/products/mobile-computer-android-scanner-p172

Yep :) I tried using a broadcast receiver but not getting far. Not sure of what to use as the action for the IntentFilter or how to get the barcode data out of the intent. Thanks..
